# Cannot read property toLowerCase of undefined using Adonis and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, adonis.js

I'm using Adonis with PostgreSQL and I am trying to implement a search where a user would be able to search through posts using the `title`

I have my code structured like so

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET" style="outline:none">
  <input class="shadow appearance-none border-2 p-2 h-10" style="outline:none" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search the forum" value="{{ request.input('q', '') }}">
</form>
```

and my controller like so

```
'use strict'

const Post = use('App/Models/Post')
const Database = use('Database')

class SearchController {
  async index ({ view, request, response, params }) {
    let posts = await Post.query()
      .forIndex()
      .whereRaw('lower(title) LIKE ?', params.searchString.toLowerCase())
      .paginate(request.input('page', 1), 10)

    return view.render('index', {
      posts
    })
  }
}

module.exports = SearchController
```

However, I am getting the following error:

[image: error]

Comment: Clearly params doesn't have a searchString property, how is it supposed to get assigned in your frontend?

Comment: @LevKuznetsov So do I need to change the form? Controller? What would be the best way to resolve this?

Comment: I would think the word searchString should somehow figure in the form, I don't know what you're using on the front end

Comment: I'm using Adonis https://adonisjs.com/ for the front-end @LevKuznetsov

Comment: @LevKuznetsov The form I have included in the post, I am also using edge templating

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `name='q'` try `name='searchString'` in the form

See https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request#_methods to get query string parameters in adonis

Comment: No joy, I'm still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`